# Getting syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '=' in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Ruby and trying to run a script ,When I am trying to run a Ruby script like below, I am getting

```
> ruby test.rb 
test.rb:53: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
  All::Config.new_global_config(domain: domain, realm: realm)
                                          ^
test.rb:53: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
  All::Config.new_global_config(domain: domain, realm: realm)
```

When I see ruby version, it says:

```
> ruby -version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]
-e:1: undefined local variable or method `rsion' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Any pointers? Is it because of the version? 1.8.x instead of 1.9 or more?

Comment: _"Is it because of the version?"_ – yes, you have to use `:domain => domain` in 1.8

Comment: `{symbol: value}` style hash is 1.9+ syntax only.

Comment: Thanks @Thermatix

Comment: Thanks @Stefan .

Answer (score 8):

The `{key: 'value'}` syntax was added in ruby `v1.9`. To do this in `v1.8`, you need to use the `{:key => 'value'}` syntax (which is still valid in modern ruby, too).

`1.8` and `1.9` are both **very old** versions!!! Neither has been supported for a long time. (1.8 was retired [in 2013](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/); 1.9 [in 2015](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/01/10/ruby-1-9-3-will-end-on-2015/).)

The latest version, at the time of writing this, is [`2.4.1`](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/03/22/ruby-2-4-1-released/). Use this if possible.

The oldest supported version of ruby is [`2.2.7`](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/03/28/ruby-2-2-7-released/).

Comment: Thanks @Tom , this was helpful